# navbar change color on click html

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, nav

I'm running into issues on my first ever website. I have successfully created a navigation bar at the top which looks and acts somewhat how I want it to (other than the color scheme but that can come later). The issue is that whenever I click a different link on the bar I want that box to change color, but it is currently stuck highlighted on the homepage. I think this is something super simple but i cannot find it. Thank you for the help.

```css
body
{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* upper strip holding the tabs*/
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #328CC1
}

li
{
    float:left;
    border-right:3px solid #30FFE3;
}


li a
{
    display: block;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;

}

li a:hover:not(.active) 
{
    background-color: #111;
}

a.active
{
    background-color: #EAB126

}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#athletics">Athletics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can also use jQuery for highlighting menu: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xLo71Lk3/)

Comment: @Div_P's solution seems to remove the ability to actually navigate, and produces 'activeTab' is not defined.  example https://jsfiddle.net/xLo71Lk3/

Comment: But you can replace the 'activeTab' line with window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
a.active
  background-color: #EAB126
}
```

to this:

```
li a:focus {
  background-color: #EAB126
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3azk428b/)

This does what you ask BUT if this is a navigation bar then bear in mind that the control will lose focus as soon as you change page. It would be better if you use Javascript/JQuery to handle that much more easily.

Comment: Just elaborating on @Ahs N's answer: even if you navigate to elsewhere on the same page, it loses focus and so the selected option won't stay "lit". e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/s7qaywe8/

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of handling this is to have each page have a class that includes the page name: `<div class="academics">` for example.

Now modify your header (within the page div) as follows:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a class="for_home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="for_academics" href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
            <li><a class="for_athletics" href="#athletics">Athletics</a></li>
            <li><a class="forcontact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

this would be followed by the css as follows:

```
.home .for_home, .academics .for_academics, .athletics .for_athletics, .contact .for_contact {
  background-color: #EAB126;
}
```

Then the menu item for the current page will be highlighted.

Congratulations on your first website!